# Spring Web MVC: Internationalization/Localization : No message found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, localization, internationalization

I can't seem to find the source for the internationalization.
I get the following error:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'label.firstname' for locale 'en'.
```

In my jsp I do:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<h1 class="page-header"><spring:message code="label.firstname"/></h1>
```

In both the message.properties there is a key-pair for:

```
label.firstname=First Name (messages_en.properties)
label.firstname=Voornaam (messages_nl.properties)
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image: project directory]
[image: dispatcher-servlet.xml]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

The properties-files should be under /WEB-INF/classes

Answer (score 0):

try to add more this:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
</bean>
```

Your resource bundles must be in your classpath.

Comment: I followed your advice, but it still has the same error :(

Comment: Still no use... Or could it be a Tomcat-specific error?